# WYSIWYG - Editor that validates source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, wysiwyg

Is there a WYSIWYG editor that is able to format code?

So when anyone inserts code into the wysiwyg editor box, it would properly format it?

Comment: Why a WYSIWYG? Why not a regular editor?

Comment: You mean besides Visual Studio?

Comment: Any specific language you would like to handle because *code* doesn't mean much? Also what does *properly format* means? Properly according  to what/whom, ...?

Comment: If you are asking about (Rich)TextBox controls, it have nothing to do with WYSIWYG...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look around at the various wysiwyg editors for asp.net, what you'll find is that most of the support syntax highlighting via a plugin.  The plugin will use a javascript library like prettify.js to do the highlighting on the client.  Sometimes they're easy to set up, sometimes not.

But you asked about *validating* in your title.  Validating is very different and a much more complicated animal.  You won't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is by eg. Microsoft Visual Studio, Microsoft Expression Web, Adobe Dreamweaver, Microsoft FrontPage etc.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to text entered into a text box on a web site.

Comment: @ChrisF: this has nothing to do with "WYSIWYG".